# Fan working non-stop on a Dell Inspiron 5110

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, power-management, fan

First of all i'm new at ubuntu. I've only tried 11.10 before 12.04. Since then my notebook's(Dell Insprion 5110) fan was working non-stop. And also battery lasts in 2 hours. So i made a research. Some said it's about graphics card driver. I've tried so many things, so many codes but i get no result.

I must say that i've tried ironhide and bumblebee. non of them worked

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ironhide and bumblebee by MrMee  are not maintained any more and cause many problems.

The only reliable solution is to use Bumblebee from http://bumblebee-project.org. **Though the name is same it work in very different way and its more reliable** I am using it in my Dell XPS 15 with Nvidia 540m.

Since your question doesn't clearly say whether you have upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, I will assume the following

1. You have done a fresh install in 12.04 and no other software is installed. Follow instruction here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

   If you have installed anything from this page https://github.com/MrMEEE,  do a fresh install of 12.04, and follow step 1
2. You have ironhide installed and upgraded from 11.10. Read here for cleaning up and upgrade instruction -> https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Upgrading-on-Ubuntu