# Fan always running in Dell Inspiron 5520

Tags: dell, fan, noise

I have Dell Inspiron 5520 laptop. Its fan is always in running state.

#### Specifications

- OS Ubuntu 12.10 x64
- CPU Intel Core I5 3rd gen
- Video Radeon 7670M.

I have checked the system monitor to check cpu ,
then i found that one cpu uses is always 100%.
[image]
What do I need to do to stop the noise from my laptop?

Comment: dual/hybird graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

Is the FAN running only under Ubuntu or with other OS too? Maybe the notebook need to be opened and cleaned...?!

Maybe its possilbe to set the temperature when the FAN should start to run to a higer value in the BIOS. **This can be dangerus, when the FAN doesen't start early enough and the notebook gets too hot.**

Comment: Yes, fan running only under Ubuntu. Laptop is new.

Comment: same problem, with windows 8 the fan stops, with ubuntu it's running non stop. brand new laptop

Answer (score 0):

[Fan working non-stop on a Dell Inspiron 5110](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128108/fan-working-non-stop-on-a-dell-inspiron-5110)

Comment: The link you have mentioned is about Dell Insprion 5110 & question is Dell Inspiron 5520 , N5110 has Nvidia card & 5520 has ATI card ( hybrid )